# Get Date Using Javascript and length of time from Select Field and then Format Date

Tags: javascript, jquery, timestamp

I want to start a jQuery countdown script for a certain number of minutes (specified from select field) from a timestamp generated when a button is clicked. The countdown timer needs the date in this format: yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss

This is the code that assigns a variable based on option chosen in select field:

```
<select id="subject-options" name="subject-options">
    <option selected disabled>Please Choose Countdown Length</option>
    <option id="3" value="3">3 Minutes</option>
    <option id="4" value="4">4 Minutes</option>
    <option id="5" value="5">5 Minutes</option>
    <option id="10" value="10">10 Minutes</option>
    <option id="15" value="15">15 Minutes</option>
    <option id="20" value="20">20 Minutes</option>
    <option id="30" value="30">30 Minutes</option>
    <option id="60" value="60">1-Hour</option>
</select>
```

The JS/JQuery code:

```
var selectedSubject = $('#subject-options option:checked').val();

$('#subject-options').on('change', function() {
  selectedSubject = $('#subject-options option:checked').val();
  console.log(selectedSubject);
});
```

And this is the jQuery for the coutndown timer:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                
    //Countup timer
    $(".countup").flipTimer({
        date:"2022/12/20 00:00:00",
        timeZone:-5,    //Time zone of New York
        past:true,
        borderRadius:2,
        bgColor:"#fff",
        dividerColor:"#666",
        digitColor:"#333",
        textColor:"#fff",
        boxShadow:false
    });
            
});
```

So, I need user to:

1. Select timer length from select field
2. Click on a button
3. Timestamp generated on button click
4. Length of time chosen in select field to be added to the timestamp
5. The new countdown timer date converted to this format yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss
6. Update date option on countdown script
7. And then fire the countdown script

I am new to Javascript & jQuery and can't figure out how to do this?

I have tried various different means of adding the number of minutes from the variable set by the first bit of jQuery code and none of them work how I need it to. I've also tried to format any timestamp in the format it requires, but had very little joy with that either.